# Table filter column in django with FilterTable jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-templates

I make a table in a django template:

```
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Company</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for user in user_list %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{% url 'user:edit_user' user %}">{{ user }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ user.userprofile.company }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to add a filter input, found this: [FilterTable](http://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/) this plugin put an input before the table but if i render the template with the django tags not work and if i put a simple table it works good, it is possible to implement that in my django template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone in the future ever need, the solution is that the plugin filter appears from 9 record in the table and when I was trying only had 3 entries

This is my jQuery call to filter from 10 records and to select an input made from myself named `input-filter`:

```
$('table').filterTable({
    filterSelector: '#input-filter',
    minRows: 10
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible.

According to the documentation you linked to it should look something like this:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/bindWithDelay.js"></script> <!-- optional -->
<script src="/path/to/jquery.filtertable.js"></script>
<style>
.filter-table .quick { margin-left: 0.5em; font-size: 0.8em; text-decoration: none; }
.fitler-table .quick:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
td.alt { background-color: #ffc; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2); }
</style> <!-- or put the styling in your stylesheet -->

<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Company</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for user in user_list %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{% url 'user:edit_user' user %}">{{ user }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ user.userprofile.company }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$('table').filterTable(); //if this code appears after your tables; otherwise, include it in your document.ready() code.
</script>
```

Note: This will only work if you installed jquery and set the paths (at the top of the code block) correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've try this but the input field not appear when i render the fields but if i put a simple table it works :/ have you tried? I'm a django beginner

Comment: Can you give me an example of such a 'simple table'?
I am not sure if I understand you correctly. :)

Comment: Thanks for try to understand me jajaja i'm from a spanish country :) i found the solution